# libsourcey & OpenCV stream example

Tags: c++11, ffmpeg, video-streaming, libsourcey

I am trying to make a second annotated web based video screen for our security cams.

Basicly we are tooling the opencv with C++11 , based solution to boxing/ovelays for important objects in the video frames . We can see locally with imshow .

We want to stream this frames so we can access through web browser based app through ip adresses.

The question is:

- What is the advised thirdparty for this simple(!) requirement (libsourcey,ffmpeg,libvl etc)
- any example for opencv to ie: mp4 streaming that we can acces from browser.

at first sight video streaming libs looks very complicated and honestly we confused.

Thanks a lot.